# Home fragment showing under other fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

please i have an issue. I am using bottom navigation and nav controller. once I switch fragments, the home fragment keeps showing under the rest

```
    navController = Navigation.findNavController(this,
        R.id.Fragment1
    )

    //appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph)
    //setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

    setupActionBarWithNavController(navController)

    bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation)

    bottomNavigationView.selectedItemId = R.id.navigation_home

    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)

    //fragmentManager.add(, HomeFragment.newInstance(), "home fragment").commit()
    fragmentManager.add(R.id.Fragment1,HomeFragment.newInstance(),"home fragment").commit()
}



override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
}

var home =  HomeFragment()
var favourites = FavouritesFragment()
var addPost = AddPostFragment()
var search = SearchFragment()
var profile = ProfileFragment()


override fun onNavigationItemSelected(p0: MenuItem): Boolean {

    when (p0.getItemId()){
        navigation_home ->{
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.Fragment1, home).commit()
            return true
        }
        navigation_favourites ->{
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.Fragment1, favourites).commit()
            return true

        }
        navigation_post ->{
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.Fragment1, addPost).commit()
            return true
        }
        navigation_search->{
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.Fragment1, search).commit()
            return true
        }
        navigation_profile ->{
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.Fragment1, profile).commit()
            return true
        }
    }

    return true
}
```

Comment: You should not be doing any FragmentTransactions if you are using NavController. Why do you have that code at all?

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not help, but add a color to the background of the fragments that are going on top of the home fragment.

So in one of the xmls of the fragments:

```
android:background="@android:color/white"
```